# Android TextView text changes color on touch, but it shouldn't

Tags: android, textview

I've encountered a strange problem where I have a TextView that I have made scrollable through XML  `android:scrollbars="vertical"` & programmatically with 
 `.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());`

When I touch the TextView, the white text changes to light gray.

If I remove the `.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());` I don't get that response.

What is causing this and how do I prevent it?

Thanks

```
     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/questionView"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="0dp"
         android:layout_weight="0.50"
         android:autoLink="none"
         android:clickable="false"
         android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
         android:fadingEdgeLength="@dimen/Fading_Edge"
         android:includeFontPadding="true"
         android:linksClickable="false"
         android:longClickable="false"
         android:padding="4dp"
         android:scrollbars="vertical"
         android:text="Question"
         android:textSize="25px"
         android:typeface="sans" />
```

Comment: can you share the XML declaration of the TextView element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using  solid colors for your textview attributes as follows

```
android:textColor="#000000"
android:textColorHighlight="#000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use to extend your class with scrollview in java code for scrollablitiy hope the textview color does not change

Answer (score -1):

try this it may help you:

```
android:focusable="false"
```

and/or

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Comment: there should be only one = instead of == . Also this solution didn't work.